# Re-election leader in case of crash with Leader Latch Curator

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator, leader

I am using leader latch Curator to implement a distributed project .
The idea is that given a set of processes/threads only one should become leader and the others follow. The leader should assign tasks to the followers and they should print out the reuslts at the end of execution.
I also need to handle any problems with the leader crashing and electing a new one .

How can I implement such logic with Leader Latch Curator?